# difference between dynamic cache and static cache in java

Tags: java, caching, web

We were looking to develop a cache mechanism and came across terms like dynamic cache and static cache.
What is dynamic cache and static cache? Can any one help me to understand with example with respect to java?

Comment: These terms have little to do with Java.

Comment: Is this really language dependent?

Comment: [this](http://www.dwbiconcepts.com/etl/14-etl-informatica/16-dynamic-lookup-cache.html) came up as one of the top google results for this - seems useful enough to get started on understanding

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I asked an example with respect to java. I didn't mean static and dynamic cache is related to java or any other language.

Answer (score 4):

To put it short, static cache is readonly cache and dynamic cache is read and write. Usage examples

Static: on program startup we load some reference data from DB table into a cache once. Now our cache returns data by key instead of making requests to DB.

Dynamic: we have Staff DAO with a cache. On getStaffById we first look in the cache and if it's there return; otherwise read it from DB put it in cache and return. On remove/update we remove/update both in cache and DB.